# how to get selected text from a dropdown in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, drop-down-menu

I have my options in an array

```
@groupings = [["Text 1", "value_1"],["Text 2", "value_2"]]
```

so im using a

```
select_tag(:groupby, options_for_select(@groupings, params[:groupby]))
```

I'd like to populate an H3 tag on the page with the selected text.  (ie "Text 2" if params[:groupby ] = "value_2" )

Is there a rails way to do this?  Other than manually deriving it from the @groupings array?

TIA, 
  Kirby

Comment: Do you mean "populate" as in render it, or "populate" as in change it dynamically when the drop-down selector is used?

Comment: apologies.. i mean place the text between the tags :-p   <h3>Text 2</h3>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe all you need is a simple `find` call, and these are often best wrapped in a helper:

```
def label_for_grouping(group_id)
  grouping = @groupings.find { |g| g[1] == group_id }

  grouping and grouping[0]
end
```

Then later:

```
<h3><%= label_for_grouping(params[:groupby]) %></h3>
```

This look-up would be easier if you had a Hash version of your `@groupings` variable, or perhaps simply kept it as a Hash and rendered it as an Array using `.to_a` where required.

Comment: i used grouping[0] || "mydefault grouping"